# Adding custom Response header to Spring WebFlux contoller endpoint

Tags: spring-webflux

Is there a way to add a response header to spring webflux controller endpoint? for example to the following method I have to add a custom header say 'x-my-header'

```
@GetMapping(value = "/search/{text}")
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
public Flux<SearchResult> search(@PathVariable(
        value = "text") String text){

        return searchService().find(text);
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the functional API, this is really easy; the `ServerResponse` builder has builders for almost everything you need.

With the annotated controllers; you can return an `ResponseEntity<Flux<T>>` and set the headers:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/search/{text}")
public ResponseEntity<Flux<SearchResult>> search(@PathVariable(
    value = "text") String text) {
    Flux<SearchResult> results = searchService().find(text);
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .header("headername", "headervalue")
            .body(results);
}
```

Note that the updated code doesn't need the `@ResponseStatus` annotation now.

**UPDATE:**
Apparently the solution above works; unless you have `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix-dashboard` dependency. In that case you can use the following code:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/search/{text}")
public Mono<ResponseEntity<List<SearchResult>>> search(@PathVariable(
        value = "text") String text) {
    return searchService().find(text)
            .collectList()
            .map(list -> ResponseEntity.ok()
                    .header("Header-Name", "headervalue")
                    .body(list));
}
```

A couple of things to note:

1. Outer type should be `Mono<ResponseEntity<T>>`: There is one response for request. If you declare it to be a `Flux`, Spring will try to deserialize the `ResponseEntity` as if it was a POJO.
2. You need to use an operator to transform the `Flux` into a `Mono`: `collectList()` or `single()` will do the job for you.

Checked with Spring Boot 2.0.3.RELEASE

Comment: Thanks a lot MuratOzkan. Just what I was looking for. BTW, is there a good resource to learn about WebFlux/reactive ?

Comment: Well, for WebFlux, it's more of a combination of the official docs + source code for me. For Project Reactor, check out the first link on https://projectreactor.io/learn for a gentle introduction to basics. A lot of RxJava stuff also apply to Reactor (+ you get to know the differences)

Comment: Strange that it isn't working for me..not sure if anything to do with my environment. I tried following

Comment: Strange that it isn't working for me..not sure if anything to do with my environment. I tried the following
1) return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .header("headername", "headervalue")
                .body(results);
2) HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("My-Header-Add", "Added-Header");
        headers.set("My-Header-Set", "Set-Header");
return  new ResponseEntity<>(response,headers,HttpStatus.OK);
But I only get following headers
HTTP/1.1 200 
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Mon, 09 Jul 2018 21:07:19

Comment: I am with spring boot 2.0.0.M3 (Spring-core and Spring-web of 5.0.0.R3) with other dependencies like spring cloud, hystrix etc its tricky to upgrade the version.

Comment: Tried by upgrading to Spring Boot 2.0.3.RELEASE with no luck. Its fustrating .. may be I am doing something stupid. I have updated the same code here [link](https://github.com/lifeRockss/Spring-boot-2.3-try2)

Comment: okay, this is weird but if I remove `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix-dashboard` dependency from my pom.xml I get my headers in the response .. tried it with 2.0.3.RELEASE in above mentioned code.

Comment: Thanks, @MuratOzkan for your updated answer on 11th July. It worked with spring boot M3 too.